# How to implement coulomb counter method for battery capacity using any micro-controller?

Tags: microcontroller, batteries

I trying to implement coulomb counter method in any micro-controller.
suggest me, any circuit ?
Or Any give idea how to implement?

Comment: Start here : http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/technical-articles/P356_EN-SOC.pdf

Comment: I dont want to use any external ic to implement.i have read some where that using simple ADC we can implement?

Comment: You have so little detail in your question, now you should add what you have just put in your comment and include details of which micro-controller you may be considering as well as details of other components, also links to the data sheets will help.

Comment: 1. i want use  stm32 controller.
 
2. I have read in this about CC  -link-https://www.richtek.com/Design%20Support/Technical%20Document/AN024

3. this IC of coulomb counter - LTC4150 Coulomb Counter IC

4. but i dont want any ic to use.

Comment: okay just tell me can we implement without any ic to know battery capacity?

Comment: A bit of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_sensing_techniques and some Ohm's law

Comment: The Richtek AN024 is actually a pretty good article. It contains all ideas and caveats. Properly selected STM32 will have enough means to implement the coulomb counter without any other ICs, although it may not have good dynamic response to fast changing loads.

Answer (score 1):

To implement energy counter for a battery, you need to measure its voltage (easy part) and the instantaneous flowing current. That's where a little problem is. You need to take DIFFERENTIAL measurements across a shunt resistor which should be kept small, and thus the differential voltage will be small too.

Without amplification of the shunt voltage you will need to have two channels of a very high-resolution ADC (say, 16+ bits) to get reasonable accuracy in current measurements. High-resolution ADC are not a part of "any microcontroller", so an upscale MCU will cost you.

Alternatively you can use a simple $1 dedicated (bi-polar) shunt converter into plain voltage, something like INA199, and use an ordinary ADC channel to take current measurements.

Better you can use a dedicated autonomous IC that does all measurements for you and reports results over I2C bus, something like INA219 IC, which can take voltage and current measurements simultaneously, and even multiply them for you.

Comment: But if one end of the shunt resistor is connected to ground, then you can just measure the voltage between the other end of the resistor and ground.  This may be easier if using an ADC.

Comment: @SimonB, true, but still you need to measure the signal in 10-s of millivolt range, that't why all gauge circuits use an amplification of 20X - 50X or something. I guess if you are not up to high accuracy, you can use even a 10-bit ADC in deep averaging mode, but you will lose accuracy if the load is fast changing. So yes, it is doable.